# select all rows for column except header in a seperate worksheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2013, vba

I've tried various ways and answers to select all of the rows except the header for a certain column and none seem to work.

I've tried using (15 is the column here):

```
 Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(.Cells(rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row, 15)).Select
```

I managed to use `.Activate` on the worksheet with a different statement to select all, but this changes the sheet and you could visibly see all the rows being selected. This isn't possible for what I need it for. Users can't have a bunch of sheets constantly being switched in front of them, makes for a bad experience.

How can I select all of the non-blank columns after the header (first) row without using `.Activate`?

I need to get these values, put them in an array, and check if the current cell value is in the array. Not asking for this part, but providing it as context if it matters.

Comment: see me answer below, it will put your data in a dynamic 2-dimension array

Comment: "How can I select all of the non-blank columns"  do you want to select all skip blank columns.  Do you mean all non-blank rows?  Do you mean all the rows in the list except the header row?

Comment: @fluffy_muffin you want to select them ? or save the values into an array ? did you test the code in my answer below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not select a range on a non-active worksheet.

Here is how you can set a reference to all the cells in a column except the header row.

```
Dim TargetRange As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set TargetRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 15), .Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp))

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads the data from the Worksheet (without using `Select` or `Activate`), and puts it in a 2-dimensional array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Range_WO_Headers()

Dim Sht_Source              As Worksheet
Dim Rng                     As Range
Dim LastRow                 As Long
Dim LastCol                 As Long
Dim Rng_Array               As Variant

' modify Sheet1 according to your sheet name
Set Sht_Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' assuming the table's data starts from Cell A1
LastRow = Sht_Source.Cells(Sht_Source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sht_Source.Cells(1, Sht_Source.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' resize array according to number of columns and number of rows
ReDim Rng_Array(0 To LastRow, 0 To LastCol)

' set dynamic array from Cell A1 to last row and last column found (starting the second row)
Set Rng = Sht_Source.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

Rng_Array = Application.Transpose(Rng)

End Sub
```